# jQuery - select nth child within <li>

Tags: jquery

i'm trying to select the `<a>` within the `<span>` that's the nth child of the `<li>`

HTML

```
<li>
 <span><a></a></span>
 <span><a></a></span>
 ......
 <span><a></a></span>
</li>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
 if ($('body').attr('class') == 'special') {
  $('li span:nth-child(1) a').css({'color' : '#444444'});
 };
});
```

what am i missing here because it doesn't seem to select the `<a>`

thanks

Comment: Works for me. See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/F2C8v/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works, [you can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BpdM2/), make sure of a few things:

What your code is running in a `document.ready` handler, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('li span:nth-child(1) a').css({'color' : '#444444'});
});
```

And that your anchors have an `href` or a `name` attribute, otherwise the browser may render them as disabled, ignoring some styling.

Comment: i have this jQuery within an if statement. the <a> tag have the href attribut but no name attribute

Comment: @pixeltocode - If you put before the same line `alert($('li span:nth-child(1) a').length);` what number do you get?

Comment: @pixeltocode - Are the elements being added dynamically?  Also an `if()` statement doesn't say anything...if it running on `document.ready` like in my code above?

Comment: @pixeltocode - Are the elements being added dynamically? AJAX, etc?

Comment: @Nick - the elements are NOT being added dynamically.

Comment: @pixeltocode - Do you have a link to the page?  Something's different from your posted question...the code you have works, provided the `<body>` does have that class.

Comment: @Nick - I've got two if statements, one that check the id of the body and another that checks the class. Does that affect it?

Comment: @pixeltocode - yup, you need to ensure that the statement is even running first

Comment: @Nick, i combined the if statements into one, it is running but the <a> is still not being selected.

Comment: @pixeltocode - I can't help you debug this...if you have a link, then that works, but currently you're asking a question and not posting the *actual* code, it's really hard to find the problem when you don't post the info.

Comment: @Nick - there was an extra <a> generated dynamically. I wasn't aware of that. So, instead of nth-child(1), I've had to use nth-child(2) and it works now. Thanks